# Unable to recover latest data from saved notepad file after hard reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10. I have a notepad file with some important information in it that I update frequently. I am 100% certain it was saved with the latest information before I needed to do a cold reboot on my computer (holding the power button down for 10 seconds).

After starting the computer up again, I notice the notepad file did not contain the latest information I saved, rather the information was from a version of it from my last reboot (over a week ago, I've been hibernating since then). This is despite the fact that the modify date was just a couple of hours before the cold reboot was required. It does sound peculiar but could it perhaps be a bug with Windows?

Is there any way I can recover the data I recently saved in this notepad file before the cold reboot? Again, I'm 100% certain it was saved with the information in it.

I realize this sounds ridiculous and the obvious answer is I didn't save it with the information I added to it. I'm certain this isn't the case, but assuming it was, would it be possible to somehow navigate through hiberfile.sys to find the recent content I added to the notepad file from my last hibernation? Would hibernation store the notepad content into hiberfile.sys if for whatever reason windows didn't save the file? How would I search hiberfile.sys for this information?

As is obvious I cannot afford to lose the information that was added to this notepad file since the last reboot.

Comment: By default, Windows caches writes to HDD, as opposed to portable media such as USB flash drives. Regrettably, this means that the data was not actually *written* to disk, Windows 95 was really bad in that respect: with "cooperative multitasking", if any *one* process crashed, all did and all cached writes were lost. Sorry about that.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying that, now it makes perfect sense! This seems ridiculous behaviour. Is there any way I can actually write a file to HDD in Windows besides restarting every time I want to save something? I read an article saying that the write should happen when the computer has sufficient resources to make the write. I remember saving this change days ago. How could it be no actual write occurred for days? There must have been some idle time to make the write. The only thing I can think of is I never closed the notepad file, it was always open.

Comment: Usually, files *are* written in a matter of seconds or minutes. If it was a few days since you tried to save the file, then it's possible that it has been written, and you might be able to find its "remains" with a disk editing tool. There are ways to force flushing of of the write-cache: 1)  turn of write caching (http://mywindowshub.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-disk-write-caching-in-windows-10/), which may slow thing a bit, or 2) use SysInternals *Sync* to flush the cache: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897438.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The file was most probably not written to the HDD/SSD from the cache.
I had this situation often with USB Sticks or ext. HDD if I copied files and didn't wait long enough before removing the device...
There is no way back.